# Optimize method to iterate to over Map<String, List<Object>>

Tags: java, collections, lambda

I have a `Map<String, List<Object>> multiFieldMap` and I need to iterate over its value set and add the value to `multiFieldsList`:

```
public List<Object> fetchMultiFieldsList() {
    List<Object> multiFieldsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : multiFieldMap.entrySet()) {
        String entityName = entry.getKey();
        List<Object> ids = entry.getValue();
        for (Object id : ids) {
            Object entity = queryService.query(entityName, queryService.property("id").eq(id));
            multiFieldsList.add(entity);
        }
    }
    return multiFieldsList;
}
```

Can this method be simplified further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this using Java 8 streams.

```
public List<Object> fetchMultiFieldsList() {
    return multiFieldMap.entrySet().stream()
      .flatMap(e -> {
          String entityName = e.getKey();
          List<Object> ids = e.getValue();
          return ids.stream()
            .map(id -> queryService.query(entityName, queryService.property("id").eq(id)));
      }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I think the code itself is relatively self-explanatory. The important bit is the usage of `flatMap` instead of `map` for the first mapping operation so that the resulting streams are concatenated, ending up with a flat list of objects rather than a list of lists.

It is unfortunate that Java does not support destructuring assignment, which would allow the first lambda expression to be a single expression of the form `(k, v) -> ...`, but it does not, so I've left the statements in for clarity.

If you are willing to omit the inner declarations, the above code can be simplified further.

```
public List<Object> fetchMultiFieldsList() {
    return multiFieldMap.entrySet().stream()
      .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
          .map(id -> queryService.query(e.getKey(), queryService.property("id").eq(id)))
      ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Whichever one you prefer is a matter of personal preference. The former has more descriptive variable names, while the latter is simpler and more functional.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the map with a multimap. Using Google's Guava `Multimap`, you don't need the nested loop / `flatMap()`:

```
private Multimap<String, Object> multiFieldMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

public List<Object> fetchMultiFieldsList() {
    return multiFieldMap.entries().stream()
        .map(e -> queryService.query(e.getKey(),
                      queryService.property("id").eq(e.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```